# Can my service extends an abstract class? Should my abstract class be @Injectable?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following code:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export abstract class ClientCacheService {
    private subscriptionId: string;
    protected getId(key :string, prefix:string=""): string {
        return `${this.subscriptionId}_${prefix}_${key}`;
    }

    constructor(subscriptionId: string) {
        this.subscriptionId = subscriptionId;
    }

    abstract setCache(key :string, prefix:string, object: any): void;
    abstract getCache(key :string, prefix:string): void;
    abstract removeCache(key :string, prefix:string): any;
}


import { ClientCacheService } from "./client-cache.service";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class SessionCacheService extends ClientCacheService {
    constructor() {
        super("TEST");
    }
    setCache(key: string, prefix: string, object: any): void {
        window.sessionStorage.setItem(this.getId(key, prefix), JSON.stringify(object));
    }    
    getCache(key: string, prefix: string): void | null {
        let res = window.sessionStorage.getItem(this.getId(key, prefix));
        return res ? JSON.parse(res) : null;
    }
    removeCache(key: string, prefix: string) {
        window.sessionStorage.removeItem(this.getId(key, prefix));
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error when I compile in production mode (`ng build --prod --output-hashing none --aot false`):

> Can't resolve all parameters for e

I have two question about this code:

- Can my `SessionCacheService` extends a Abstract class?
- This abstract class should be `@Injectable()` or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Yes, your concrete implementation of service class can `extend`
   abstract class
2. No, base class does not need to (in fact it should
   not to be) annotated

Regarding point 2, just consider what `@Injectable` means to Angular? It's a sign for hierarchical injector, that this class can be injected into other class via dependency injections. What is injected? Class instance. Can abstract classes be instantiated? Not really :)

Issue you are getting while building for `--prod` is related with dead code elimination and tree shaking I suppose, where all `@Injectable` instances are reference-traced to check if they are really needed in any hierarchical call.